# How to use Maximize correctly?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I would like to Maximize this fairly simple expression

```
Maximize[{2^(-1-n)*(1+k)^(-1-n)*(1+2k)^(-1+n)*(-1 - 2 k + n)*(-2 k + n),k<=n/2, k>=1},
         {n,k}, Integers]
```

However Mathematica just returns the query. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In new versions of Mathematica this can be done as follows.

```
NMaximize[{2^(-1 - n)*(1 + k)^(-1 - n)*(1 + 2 k)^(-1 + n)*(-1 - 2 k + 
 n)*(-2 k + n), k <= n/2 && k >= 1 && {n, k} \[Element] Integers}, {n, k}, 
 Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 1}, MaxIterations -> 200]
```

> `{0.262796, {n -> 9, k -> 1}}`

The result of

```
DiscretePlot3D[Piecewise[{{2^(-1 - n)*(1 + k)^(-1 - n)*(1 + 2 k)^(-1 + n)*(-1 - 
   2 k + n)*(-2 k + n), k <= n/2}, {0, True}}], {n, 2, 12}, {k, 1,   10}]
```

[image]

confirms it.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know differential evolution would ever be the best method

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the constraint on "n" because "n" can have many possibilities, as you can see in the figure.

```
Funcion[n_, k_] := 2^(-1 - n)*(1 + k)^(-1 - n)*(1 + 2 k)^(-1 + n)*(-1 - 2 k + 
 n)*(-2 k + n);

Plot3D[Funcion[n, k], {n, 0, 100}, {k, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your "answer" is more like a comment than an answer.  To improve it, provide a constraint on `n`, as you suggest, and post the answer you get.

Comment: As it can be shown that for   n >= 10 , the result "n" which maximizes the objective function, does not vary significantly, provided that the result is an integer, therefore, it could be solved as follows.

     Maximize[{2^(-1 - n) (1 + k)^(-1 - n) (1 + 2 k)^(-1 +  n) (-1 - 2 k + n) (-2 k + n), 1 <= k <= n/2 && n <= 10}, {n, k},  Reals] // N

(*{0.264166, {n -> 9.48805, k -> 1.}}*)

Answer (score -1):

Try NMaximize.

```
Maximize[{2^(-1-n)(1+k)^(-1-n)(1+2k)^(-1+n)(-1 - 2 k + n)(-2 k + n),k<=n/2, k>=1},{n,k}]
```

Comment: What result do you get?